# how do i clear block lag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so, in a singleplayer world, i just got a lag that looks like multiplayer lag.

there's like a delay between things, (when i push a button, it took longer to go back to normal. when i attack a mob (any type), they got damage, but the knockback is slow, like if they were in slow motion. etc.)

how do i fix this ??

i got this problem when playing a map. well, the map is kinda huge.
then i got this problem too when im playing single player with like 15 mods or so.

is this because my computer can't handle it ??

Answer (score 1):

Since some version pretty long ago, singleplayer no longer differs from multiplayer - the game still runs a server inside, and client communicates with it.

Generally yes, it means that your computer has not enough processing power to handle all it needs to. I usually don't experience it, but I do when I start a new world - the game is busy generation the world and processing new chunks, so it has less time to process mob AI (including them being hit) and block updates.

You can try to allocate more memory to Java runtime in launcher (click Edit profile - JVM arguments - change `-Xmx` parameter to larger values), or reduce render distance in Minecraft options.

If none of this helps, and it is definitely related to a certain map (you don't get lags on simpler maps / with less mods), then, unfortunately, it is a problem of your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can deduce your computer is unable to handle what the game is loading.  In Minecraft entities are a large source for lag.  This includes mobs, but also large amounts of unspawned items.

Here is what I suggest you do

```
Change video settings.
```

If your Render Distance is high and your computer is trying to load a mass amount of chunks than this could cause your PC to lag. You can also turn Particles to low, Graphics to fast, and Clouds off.

```
Turn VBO's on
```

If you look in the Minecraft menu under Options then Video Settings You should see Use VBO's this is supposed to increase your FPS 5 to 10%

You can read more on VBO's here

```
Remove any possible lag content
```

Such as Mobs and other entities, snow, decaying leaves and more

Click [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112123/what-game-mechanics-in-minecraft-introduce-lag?rq=1) to see all the tings that can cause lagg

The last thing you could do is install a lag reducing tool like OptiFine.
OptiFine is great for lag reducing and frankly makes things look coller

There are plenty tutorials online on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Although one of the other responses is most likely the problem, because you are using a map, it is possible that the gamerule `randomTickSpeed`
is set to a much higher number than usual. To remedy this, press `ESC`, then `Open to LAN`, change `Allow Cheats` to `ON`, press `Start LAN World`, amd then type this in the chat: `/gamerule randomTickSpeed 3`. This is most likely not the problem, but it never hurts to check, as the world creator could have changed this setting from default.